# Android BroadcastReceiver get data from other Activity [ Different File ]

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-broadcast

Sorry first,

i've create Android Project that based on IOIO,
my application is like logging application, here i have 2 java file the first file is MainActivity.java and the second one is AlarmReceiver.java
the problem is, when MainActivity executing AlarmReceiver.java using AlarmManager method

[ `_AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, _PendingIntent)` ]

the AlarmReceiver.java automatically will execute

`onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` which in there will execute

`_CsvFileExporter.Export(_File, new MainActivity().getData());`

and Error appear caused by NullPointerException on method called from AlarmReceiver > onReceive >

`new MainActivity().getData()` and here the code in getData()

```
try{
TextView    tvwBattery  =   (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvwBatteryLevel);
TextView    tvwIOIO     =   (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvwWaterLevel);
String asd = (String) tvwBatteryLevel.getText();
return asd;
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e(TAG_LOG, "ERROR " + e.getMessage());
}
```

error actually at findViewById... why ??
is there another way to get data from MainActivity.java [ data from MainActivity to AlarmReceiver ] ?

Sorry for bad english

Comment: You'd never ever invoke `new MainActivity()`. Read up on the activity life cycle (you can google those words).

Answer (score 0):

Have you put a receiver in the Manifest ?

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.application.YourReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

I don't anderstand what you really want to do. If you use an intent you can also put something in.

Comment: This is not the primary problem.